# Yesterday date will compare to the filename of .txt

Tags: date, batch-file, if-statement, robocopy

My codes are from some post here as well and I am using robocopy so that I can move the files instead of copy and pasting them.

Here are my information

```
**result** = my yesterdays date
**Source Path** = where the main file is.
**Destination Path** = where it should be move
```

I am trying to move a file wherein it was dated yesterday from source to destination.

```
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "result=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%"
echo %result%

FOR /R %C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback UP% %%G IN (*.txt) DO (
set file=%%~nG

ROBOCOPY "C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback UP" "C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback UP\Destination" "*.txt" /mov
If "%result%"=="*.txt" (
    echo Filename "%file%" has been backed up
) else (
    echo Filename "%file%" nothing to back up yesterday
)
```

Comment: `if "%result%"=="*.txt"` will try and match yesterdays date string `result` with the string `*.txt` in other words something like `if "20191225"=="*.txt"` which will never match. Additionally, you need to wrap paths with spaces with double quotes and not percentage. `%C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback UP%` should be `"C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback UP"`

Comment: To be more specific sir @GerhardBarnard I need to move this file from source to detination ```WithdrawalConfirm20191225.txt``` that is why I need -1 of the current date then if it founds a yesterdays date it will the files to destination

Comment: So you have multiple files in the source folder but contains the date at the end for each? or a single file only?

Comment: Yes it is multiple maybe around 2-3 files but their unique and same strings are YYYYMMDD

Comment: ok, Let me have a look quick and will post an answer, even though it is still a little unclear.

Comment: feel free to ask sir @GerhardBarnard just to guide you well

Comment: @GerhardBarnard sir I need your help again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested as I cannot setup a replication of your environment right now.

We would simply need to match each file in the source directory to end with the date and extention, then copy each file only if it matches, test the destination file to see if it exist. You can use copy instead of robocopy.

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback_UP"
set "destination=C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback_UP\Destination"
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "result=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%"
echo %result%

for /r "%source%" %%G in (*%result%.txt) do (
copy /Y "%%~fG" "%destination%"
if exist "%destination%\%%~nxG" (
    echo File "%%~fG" backed up
    ) else (
    echo File "%%~fG" was not backed up
   )
)
pause
```

As a side note, if your intention was to `move` the files instead of copy, simply replace `copy` with `move`

Comment: Ill try this immediately and will give you a feedback!

Comment: I am willing to wait when you have a time to test. Because I tried it CMD just pops-up :)

Comment: because you ran it by double click, Add `pause` to the bottom of the script, as I have edited now. Also make sure you source and destinations are updated in my above examples

Comment: I added ```pause``` earlier but it just pops up, yep I change it .

```for /r "%C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback_UP%" %%G in ("*%result%.txt") do (
mov "%%~fG" "%C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback_UP\Destination%"
if exist "%C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Forback_UP\Destination%%%~nxG" (
    echo File "%%~fG" backed up
    ) else (
    echo File "%%~fG" was not backed up
   )
)```

Comment: no. That is wrong. You added the `%` again. I have edited my script with the correct paths, you copy it as is then and run it without  changes.

Comment: Also note that the source and destination variables have been pre-set, that makes it easier for you in future to make changes to them instead of having to actually make changes down in the script itself. So copy the script as is and test.